# Why are some udev workers timing out?

Tags: linux, udev, kernel-module

A few weeks ago, ALSA and USB stopped working on my laptop. Things like YouTube videos just don't have sound in Firefox; `mpv` prints `[ao/alsa] Playback open error: No such file or directory. Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.`. `alsamixer` complains that there's no such file as `mixer`. Flash drives don't show up in `/dev` or `/dev/disk`, and their LEDs don't come on. Oddly enough, I can still use the ports to charge my phone…

`udev` seems to be acting up, too, stalling boots for a full minute (on its own!) `waiting for uevents to be processed ...` and stalling shutdowns for a half minute (I timed it) `stopping udev ...`. It complains to the kernel log, too:

```
<28>[  130.669180] udevd[1745]: worker [1763] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0 is taking a long time
<28>[  130.669196] udevd[1745]: worker [1762] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0 is taking a long time
```

And, a couple minutes later:

```
[  251.500125] udevd[1745]: worker [1763] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0 timeout; kill it
[  251.500156] udevd[1745]: seq 1333 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0' killed
[  251.500166] udevd[1745]: worker [1762] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0 timeout; kill it
[  251.500174] udevd[1745]: seq 1336 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0' killed
[  251.500535] udevd[1745]: worker [1763] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[  251.500540] udevd[1745]: worker [1763] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0'
```

Those PCI addresses turned out to be for the USB controller and audio device, respectively. Also, I noticed that while `lsmod` doesn't seem to show anything unusual, `/proc/modules` lists `xhci_pci`, `snd_hda_intel`, and `sunrpc` as eternally `Loading`. `modprobe` on these three (and others that depend on them) will hang (`-v` shows that it hangs while trying to `insmod` them).

The system runs Gentoo on Linux 4.4.6. udev is provided by eudev 3.1.5. The root filesystem is in a LUKS container; I use an initrd to boot.

Web and Stack Exchange searches didn't turn up anything helpful. I've checked my kernel config against [the wiki's excerpt](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udev#Kernel) and tried reemerging `eudev` (no change). So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>While I don't have a full explanation, **disabling `TIMER_STATS` in the kernel config** (that's `Kernel hacking` ➔ `Collect kernel timers statistics` if you use the menuconfig) seems to have fixed this.</strike>

I'd guess that, for some reason, some of my modules fail to load with `TIMER_STATS` on, in some weird way that makes `insmod` hang. The two `udev` workers mentioned in the kernel log try to load them, hang, and then get killed. Lacking kernel modules and whatever setup `udev` would have done, sound- and USB-related things…don't work.

---

**UPDATE:**

I realized that a lot of modules were getting loaded *before* `/` was mounted. Was *very* confused until I dug into my initrd and found that it had its *own* `/lib/modules`, with copies of some modules (including `xhci_pci` and `sunrpc`). Even though I'd made sure to install all modules to the root filesystem after rebuilding them, I never rebuilt the initrd, which meant that the running kernel had a different config than (some of) the modules it was trying to load. Evidently, this resulted in Weird Things. Like `insmod` hanging.

So, if you use an initrd and it has copies of kernel modules, **make sure to rebuild it when you rebuild your kernel.**